# Audio classification with Keras: presence of human voice

Tags: audio, machine-learning, keras, classification

I'd like to create an audio classification system with Keras that simply determines whether a given sample contains human voice or not. Nothing else. This would be my first machine learning attempt.

This audio preprocessor exists. It claims not to be done, but it's been forked a few times:

https://github.com/drscotthawley/audio-classifier-keras-cnn

I don't understand how this one would work, but I'm ready to give it a try:

https://github.com/keunwoochoi/kapre

But let's say I got one of those to work, would the rest of the process be similar to image classification? Basically, I've never fully understood when to use Softmax and when to use ReLu. Would this be similar with sound as it would with images once I've got the data mapped as a tensor?

Comment: I'm also developing an application to determine whether a given sample contains human voice (instead of any other possible sound). Have you achieved good results with Keras?

Comment: @eje211 could you kindly share your progress code? I'm working on a similar problem. If I train a model on a dog bark, I want model to identify where all does the dog bark occur in a test file.

Comment: I did this at a previous job. I no longer have access to the code. Sorry. But my employer was not that interested in me pursuing this, so I didn't get very far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds can be seen as a 1D image and be worked with with 1D convolutions. 
Often, dilated convolutions may do a good work, see [Wave Nets](https://deepmind.com/blog/wavenet-generative-model-raw-audio/)

Sounds can also be seen as sequences and be worked with RNN layers (but maybe they're too bulky in amount of data for that)

For your case, you need only one output with a `'sigmoid'` activation at the end and a `'binary_crossentropy'` loss.

- Result = 0 -> no voice
- Result = 1 -> there's voice

**When to use 'softmax'?**

The softmax function is good for multiclass problems (not your case) where you want only one class as a result. All the results of a softmax function will sum 1. It's intended to be like a probability of each class.

It's mainly used at the final layer, because you only get classes as the final result.

It's good for cases when **only one class is correct**. And in this case, it goes well with the loss `categorical_crossentropy`.

**Relu and other activations in the middle of the model**

These are not very ruled. There are lots of possibilities. I often see relu in image convolutional models.

Important things to know are they "ranges". What are the limits of their outputs?

- Sigmoid: from 0 to 1 -- at the end of the model this will be the best option for your presence/abscence classification. Also good for models that want many possible classes together.
- Tanh: from -1 to 1
- Relu: from 0 to limitless (it simply cuts negative values)
- Softmax: from 0 to 1, but making sure the sum of all values is 1. Good at the end of models that want only 1 class among many classes.

Comment: Thanks! I'll get started on that.

And I think I get it. My final result will give a likelihood of 0 to some max value for human voice. Sigmoid will normalize from 0 to 1. Then, it'll be up to me to find out which value between 0 and 1 really means presence of human voice.

Comment: Normally, you create your "true labels" or load them from some dataset. All samples with human voice you classify as 1, and all samples without human voice you classify as 0. Then you train with this data, and your model will bring some kind of probability of there being a voice. Roughly, when your model predicts something near zero, it has no voice, and when it predicts things near 1, there is voice. If your model predicts things in the middle, then your model is not very sure....

Answer (score 1):

Oftentimes it is useful to preprocess the audio to a spectrogram:

[image: Spectogram]

Using this as input, you can use classical image classification approaches (like convolutional neural networks). In your case you could divide the input audio in frames of around 20ms-100ms (depending on the time resolution you need) and convert those frames to spectograms. Convolutional networks can also be combined with recurrent units to take a larger time context into account.

It is also possible to train neural networks on raw waveforms using 1D Convolutions. However research has shown that preprocessing approaches using a frequency transformation achieve better results in general.